# Why does C# remove my second xml namespace attribute when building this XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlNameSpacingTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode baseNode = output.CreateElement("idat");
            XmlAttribute xmlnsAttribute = output.CreateAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
            xmlnsAttribute.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            baseNode.Attributes.Append(xmlnsAttribute);
            XmlAttribute xsiAttribute = output.CreateAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation");
            xsiAttribute.Value = "C:\\sub.xsd";
            baseNode.Attributes.Append(xsiAttribute);
            output.AppendChild(baseNode);
            // DumbSubNode
            XmlNode firstNode = output.CreateElement("Sub-Node1");
            firstNode.InnerText = "Single Sub-Node";
            baseNode.AppendChild(firstNode);
            output.Save("Test.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect an output of:

```
<idat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\sub.xsd">
  <Sub-Node1>Single Sub-Node</Sub-Node1>
</idat>
```

But I get an output of:

```
<idat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\sub.xsd">
  <Sub-Node1>Single Sub-Node</Sub-Node1>
</idat>
```

On the XmlAttribute xsiAttribute it's taking away the "xsi:" and I don't know why. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your xsiAttribute to include the Schema namespace.

```
XmlAttribute xsiAttribute = output.CreateAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xsiAttribute.Value = "C:\\sub.xsd";
```

This will produce the correct XML:

```
<idat xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\sub.xsd">
   <Sub-Node1>Single Sub-Node</Sub-Node1>
</idat>
```

The `xsi` prefix attribute is defined in Namesapce `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. If you don't specify the URI namespace then it will be considered as unidentified attribute for `xsi` and so the `xsi` was removed.
For more information see https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi.noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Comment: That was the ticket. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -2):

had a quick scan read try this 
  XmlAttribute xsiAttribute = output.CreateAttribute("xsi:" + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation");

and do let me know if it has work

cheers bud

Comment: Gave it a try and it did not work. Someone downvoted you while I was commenting. Wasn't me. I don't have the required 125 reputation to downvote someone.

Comment: @BradB. but you *would* downvote if that does not work at all, would not you?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I prefer education to down voting. A down vote teaches nothing. Saying that "xsi:" + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" is exactly the same as "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" because of the nature of the order of operations and string objects is preferred to just giving them a down vote.

Comment: @BradB. so you want every other person finding q/a pair try  answer you know is absolutely wrong and waste their time on it? That is a goal, I would not call it noble one, but I respect your choice. (Also you may want to reconsider your point of view to align better with site's purpose).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think my views align with the purpose of this place generally fine. Sites purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/company/about. If I have the ability to teach someone something I will gladly do it as I am thankful for everyone who teaches me something. A down vote with no explanation teaches the wrong lesson.